# Django queryset difference method loosing ordering

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to use Django's built in difference method on a queryset but it seems ordering is gone after the difference method is used.

```
objects = self.get_index_children()
print("objects are %s ordered" % objects.ordered)

featured_recipes = objects.filter(featured=True)[:3]
print("featured_recipes are %s ordered" % featured_recipes.ordered)

latest_recipes = objects.difference(featured_recipes)
print("latest_recipes are %s ordered" % latest_recipes.ordered)  




objects are True ordered
featured_recipes are True ordered
latest_recipes are False ordered . <----
```

Is this supposed to be like this or bug on django side ?
if so is there any proper way of finding difference between 2 querysets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`difference()` translates into an `EXCEPT` clause whose syntax depends on the database backend.

For SQLite, Django throws an error when using ordered querysets on either side of `difference()`.

For Postgres, ordering of the subqueries is allowed, but it only affects the subqueries (which only makes sense however when the subquery is sliced).

With both backends, to order the resulting query, you need to add an explicit `.order_by(...)` to the resulting queryset:

```
q3 = q1.difference(q2).order_by('name')
```

Regarding your last question, here's the [docs for `difference`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.difference). The function returns a queryset containing the elements in one queryset minus the elements in one or more other querysets. Ordering has no direct relevance here.